# Django, multiple ModelAdmin for one Model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I have Django 1.7.9 and python 2.7. I need multiple ModelAdmin 
for one Model. One of them is standart and others with some 
constant values. For example, I have model Item with foreign key 
Categiries. I need model admin to create Item with constant 
value for every category. How can I do it? Is it possible?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a proxy model - that will allow you to register it in admin as a different model, but it will be still the same:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass

class MyModelAgain(MyModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(MyModel)
admin.site.register(MyModelAgain)
```

Comment: When I add 'using proxy true', then I am able to delete the object.

Answer (score 2):

Proxy model approach can make you some troubles with permissions (proxy model has their own permissions).

You can serve second ModelAdmin manually by URL like `/admin/<app>/<model>/<id>/alternate_view/`:

```
class YourModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        alternate_admin = SecondModelAdmin(self.model, self.admin_site)

        from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
        def wrap(view):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

            return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

        urlpatterns = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        urls = patterns('',url(r'^(.+)/alternate_view/$', wrap(alternate_admin.change_view), name='svod_analisys'))
        return urls + urlpatterns
```